# Using Azure Logic App to Insert Response from SurveyGizmo via HTTP Post (JSON)

Tags: json, sql-server, azure-logic-apps

SurveyGizmo provides a "webhook" that posts data to a given URL as JSON or a simple post.  I need to insert this data into a SQL Server database in Azure.  I am able to get the trigger (the post) to initiate the app but am having difficulty extracting the data out of the JSON submitted.

I used webhook.site to get a sample of the JSON sent via SurveyGizmo.  I used this to paste into the "sample payload" for the schema under the trigger (HTTP Request).  I see the data, the field names, etc.  in the sample but I can't seem to get values out of it in my second step which is the insert record into SQL Server.  I'll paste the sample JSON below.  What I see when I select a "parameter" under the SQL part is many, many "answer" choices under dynamic content.  I see that is repeated many times in the below sample so I'm thinking it's just not reading the schema correctly or I need to write out the schema.  Any thoughts?

```
{
  "is_test_data": null,
  "session_id": "1567451759_5d6d6a6f705997.66294551",
  "language": "English",
  "date_started": "2019-09-02 15:15:59 EDT",
  "link_id": null,
  "url_variables": [

  ],
  "ip_address": "99.85.42.146",
  "referer": "https:\/\/app.surveygizmo.com\/builder\/test\/id\/5147523",
  "user_agent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/70.0.3538.102 Safari\/537.36 Edge\/18.18362",
  "response_time": null,
  "data_quality": [

  ],
  "survey_data": {
    "3": {
      "id": 3,
      "type": "TEXTBOX",
      "question": "Please enter your email address.\u00a0 Doing so will allow you to retrieve your individual report at a later date.",
      "section_id": 1,
      "answer": "adan13@example.net",
      "shown": true
    },
    "119": {
      "id": 119,
      "type": "HIDDEN",
      "question": "org",
      "section_id": 1,
      "answer": "",
      "answer_id": 0,
      "shown": true
    }
}
```

I expect that by choosing "ip_address" for example the app would insert "99.85.42.146".  But I get nothing in the field ("parameter") I chose.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjeFe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding , SurveyGizmo will post json data to your logic app and your logic app will accept the json data and insert part of this data into your SQL server. 
Firstly, you create use a http trigger with JSON schema below :

```
{
    "properties": {
        "data_quality": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "date_started": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "ip_address": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "is_test_data": {},
        "language": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "link_id": {},
        "referer": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "response_time": {},
        "session_id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "survey_data": {
            "properties": {
                "3": {
                    "properties": {
                        "answer": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "question": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "section_id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "shown": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        },
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "119": {
                    "properties": {
                        "answer": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "answer_id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "question": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "section_id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "shown": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        },
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "url_variables": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "user_agent": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

And then create a SQL sever insert action , with the config you need.
In this demo , I created a simple table in my sql server , I'll extract ip_address from JSON and then save it to SQL server : 
[image]

[image]

As schema has been defined correctly , you can pick params you need here.

Save and run this logic app using the json data you provided, everything works as expected : 
[image]
[image]

If you have any unclear , pls feel free to let me know : )

Hi, Mike , if you want to test this logic app with your custom JSON data, you can just use some some http client tools such as postman or rest client  to do some test, you will get a 202 code if you triggered it successfully :
[image]

You can find the http trigger url here : 
[image]

As you can see , when I post the json , a new ip record as been inserted :

[image]

Btw, I have no freelance work now, so what can I help ?

Comment: My word, the fact you put that much thought into your response is so wonderful of you!  Thank you so much.  I'll follow along with your directions and re-post to let you and/or anyone who this might help see the result.  All the very best to you!!

Comment: @MikeK Welcome ! Pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark my answer if my suggestions are helpful for you : ) If there is anything unclear , pls feel free to let me know . Have a nice day !

Comment: Stanley, how do you "run it using the json data..."?   Records are being inserted but the fields are null.  The "run" seems to generate its own output from the trigger and as you can see from the screnshot there's not data, just a header.

Comment: @MikeK No, if there anything that I can help, pls email 530460414@qq.com